# MouseEnter with hook

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm hooking my form with middle click. And for now i middle click to hook my form then middle click again to trigger my method to draw on my picturebox (which is on my form).

I'd like to middle click once and instantly draw on my picturebox instead of two middle click. I tried MouseHover and MouseEnter with this code :

```
private void PbxDrawing_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bMoving = true;
    Point pos = PbxDrawing.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
    x = pos.X;
    y = pos.Y;
}
```

Mouse move :

```
private void PbxDrawing_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(bMoving && x!=-2 && y != -2)
    {
       g.DrawLine(pen,new Point(x,y), e.Location);
       x = e.X;
       y = e.Y;
    }
}
```

It allows me to know the position of the cursor and draw but to draw i've to release middle click .

How can i draw from 1 middle click if my middle click was made outside of my form ?

Edit : Clarify question

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the Middle Button is down in the MouseMove event:

```
private void PbxDrawing_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle)
    {
        x = e.X;
        y = e.Y;
    }
}

private void PbxDrawing_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle)
    {
        g.DrawLine(pen, new Point(x, y), e.Location);
        x = e.X;
        y = e.Y;
    }
}
```

Your use of `g` is a red flag, though. Is `g` created with `PbxDrawing.CreateGraphics()`? If yes, this is wrong and should be refactored to use the `e.Graphics` from the Paint() event of the PictureBox.

Comment: Graphics g; this is what i use. And i already tried your code before posting the question, I've to click 2 times on middle click

Comment: Of course `g` is a Graphics; what else would you be drawing on? The point was HOW the Graphics was created. In a bare bones application, I was able to draw with the middle mouse using a SINGLE CLICK and DRAG. You haven't represented your problem well enough for us to understand the problem...

Comment: Yes i use creategraphics from my pbxDrawing, and i tried your code and it works on a fresh project But I dont understand why it doesn't work on mine. The only difference I see is that I hook my form with a middle click and set it to toplevel

Comment: What do you mean by "I hook my form with a middle click"? That is not standard terminology.  If you want help to find the difference then we need to see more code and understand better what your app is doing.